# How to show paragraph only for a few seconds and then hide it using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am submitting form to the server and if everything is ok I want to show some kind of confirmation message for the user.

The problem is that I'm using `ASP.NET MVC 4` where I can do this:

```
@if (ViewBag.ConfirmMessage != null)
{ 
<p>@ViewBag.ConfirmNMessage</p>
}
```

but this way the messages stays which I think will be confusing for the user. If I use something like :

```
 @if (ViewBag.ConfirmMessage != null)
{ 
    <script>
        alert("Some message");
    </script>
}
```

but first `alert` works differently from showing a paragraph and also the `ViewBag.ConfirmMessage` already has the message that I want to display and in the future it will be more maintainable if I show the message from `ViewBag.ConfirmMessage` than to write some message in every view.

So my question is how I can hide `<p>@ViewBag.ConfirmNMessage</p>` after `X` seconds if it's shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`setTimeout()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

```
function fun() {
  $('p').hide();  //better to have id selector
}

var inter = setTimeout(fun, 1000); //1000 represents 1 second
```

Also a simple way using [**`fadeOut()`**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) without using `setTimeout()`

```
$("p").fadeOut( 1000, "linear", complete ); //better to have id selector
```

Comment: Could you explain me what's the meaning of having `var inter =..`? and what does `var inter` represents?

Comment: @Leron inter holds the setTimeout() function.  So you can clear/pause using this variable like `clearTimeout(inter);`

Comment: Soryy I am JS novice but I really want to understand - I have the function that holds the logic, but how exactly the function is triggered? I thought I have to bind it to some event...

Comment: @Leron Ok first check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bCYT7/.  See jQuery provide more effects options like fadeIn, fadeOut, fadeToggle,...  Here when you click the button `p` tag is (shown)fadedIn then after a few 4 seconds it will be hidden with `fadeOut()`(hidden)

Answer (score 5):

```
@if (ViewBag.ConfirmMessage != null)
{ 
<p id="confirmMsg">@ViewBag.ConfirmNMessage</p>
}
```

And

```
@if (ViewBag.ConfirmMessage != null)
{ 
    <script>
    setTimeout(function() {

        $('#confirmMsg').hide();
    }, X * 1000);
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
  <div class="wrap">
  <p>Fade this out</p>
  </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.wrap p').fadeOut(); 
 }, 400); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aTayuTAP/2/)**

Comment: All answers are good, still I can accept only one. Sowmya made the effort to provide demo and I like `fadeOut` more than `hide`. I will replace `p` with some class selector in the real code, few people already noticed that using `'p'` directly is not a good approach.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Oh god tat was just an example. Anyways edited my answer

Comment: @Sowmya Just to let you know. Here in your code, there is no need for `setTimeout` because `fadeOut()` has this option within itself like `$('.wrap p').fadeOut(1000);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').show("slow").delay(4000).hide("slow");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qxR95/

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (ViewBag.ConfirmMessage != null)
{ 
<p id="myMessage">@ViewBag.ConfirmNMessage</p>
<script>
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myMessage").hide();
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
}
```